I am recieving a NoReverseMatch error does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
Im trying to allow the user to edit an existing entry. But when I include
new_entry.html
`{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    <p> <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topic' topic.id %}">{{ topic }}</a></p>

    <p>Add a new entry:</p>
    <form action="{% url 'learning_logs:new_entry' topic.id %}" method='post'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_div}}
        <button name='submit'>Add entry</button>
    </form>

{% endblock content %}`

The site throws a NoReverseMatch at /topics/1/ Not too sure where to start looking to solve this issue. Still fairly new to django.
Rest of my code bellow
views.py
def new_entry(request, topic_id):
    """Add a new entry for a particular topic."""
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)

    if request.method !='POST':
        #No data submitted; reate a blank form
        form = Entry()
    else:  
        #POST data submitted; process data
        form =EntryForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_entry = form.save(commit=False)
            new_entry.topic = topic 
            new_entry.save()
            return redirect('learning_logs:topic', topic_id=topic_id)
        
    #Display a blank or invalid form
        context = {'topic': topic, 'form': form}
        return render(request, 'learning_logs/new_entry.html', context)

urls.py
    app_name = 'learning_logs'
urlpatterns = [
    #Home page
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    #Page that shows all topics.
    path('topics/', views.topics, name='topics'),
    #Detail page for a single topic
    path('topics/<int:topic_id>/', views.topic, name='topic'),
    #Page for adding a new topic
    path('new_topic/', views.new_topic, name='new_topic'),
    #Page for adding a new entry
    path('new_entry/<int:topic_id>/', views.new_entry, name='entry'),
]


You don't have any URL pattern named new_entry, i.e. {% url 'learning_logs:new_entry' topic.id %} should be {% url 'learning_logs:entry' topic.id %} instead.

The name=... of your new entry is name='entry', not new_entry, so "{% url 'learning_logs:entry' topic.id %}"

The error is because your app learning_logs doesn't have the url which name='new_entry'.
{% url 'learning_logs:new_entry' topic.id %}

you have given the name in urls.py has name='entry' so you have to change to.
{% url 'learning_logs:entry' topic.id %}


In your urlpatterns list, you have the name parameter for new_entry as entry:
path('new_entry/<int:topic_id>/', views.new_entry, name='entry'),

But you're trying to access it as new_entry in your new_entry.html:
<form action="{% url 'learning_logs:new_entry' topic.id %}" method='post'>

I'm guessing you meant to use new_entry as your name parameter in your URLConf. Thus use this to fix your error:
path('new_entry/<int:topic_id>/', views.new_entry, name='new_entry'),

Note that the name parameter is useful for URL reversing. Django provides tools for performing URL reversing that match the different layers where URLs are needed:

In templates: Using the url template tag (like you did in new_entry.html).
In Python code: Using the reverse() function.
In higher level code related to handling of URLs of Django model instances: The get_absolute_url() method.
See the docs.

